# C# foreach low performance

Tags: c#, performance, foreach, printing, backgroundworker

i'm developing a program that prints on thermal printer (you know, POS printers, etc)
The idea is to allow my webapps to print on this printers directly without problems (like zebra for example)
Any away, the problem is that for big documents, it takes +/- 40 seconds to print.
I've made a little debug, and the order enters directly in the job, however, is the foreach (line) that is slow.

There's a long time since the last time that I've developed in c#, so maybe someone can help me improving the speed

```
try
{
    var printc = new PrintC();
    var y = 0;

    List<int> col = null;
    int tcol = 0;

    Font f;
    SizeF TestSize;
    Conversor convert = new Conversor();

    PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
    p.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "RESGEST";
    p.PrintPage += delegate (object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
    {
        Graphics g = e1.Graphics;

        f = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);

        dynamic obj = objeto.GetValue("el");
        foreach (dynamic item in obj)
        {
            switch ((string)item.type)
            {
                case "font":
                   // Console.WriteLine("Font: size-" + item.GetValue("size"));
                    f = new Font("Arial", (int)item.size, FontStyle.Regular);
                    break;
                case "text":
                    TestSize = g.MeasureString((string)item.texto, f);
                    TestSize = g.MeasureString((string)item.texto, f, convert.w(TestSize, (string)item.w, p, tcol));

                    int tmpy;

                    e1.Graphics.DrawString(
                        (string)item.texto, //texto
                        f, //font
                        new SolidBrush(convert.cor((string)item.cor)), //font color
                        printc.container(p, 
                        e1, 
                        convert.x((string)item.x, TestSize, p, col, tcol), //pos x
                        y, //pos y
                        convert.w(TestSize, (string)item.w, p, tcol), //width
                        tmpy = convert.h(TestSize, (string)item.h, p),  //height
                        convert.cor((string)item.background)), //background
                        printc.align((string)item.align) //align
                        );

                    if (col == null)
                    {
                        y += tmpy;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        col.Add( tmpy);
                    }
                    break;
                case "col":
                    if ((string)item.size == "0")
                    {
                        int maxValue = col.Max();
                        y += maxValue;
                        col = null;
                        tcol = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        col = new List<int>();
                        tcol = Int32.Parse((string)item.size);
                    }
                    break;
                case "line":
                    e1.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, convert.psize((string)item.size)), 0, y += 10, (int)p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, y);
                    y += 10;
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    p.Print();


}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Write("Erro " + e);
}
```

This code is running inside of a worker that reads the data from the server and send it to this function
best regards

Comment: The frequent use of dynamic typing probably isn't helping - do you really need that? Next, have you profiled the code at all?

Comment: I suspect it's the use of 'Dynamic' in the foreach, not the foreach itself. This looks through every type in every referenced assembly to find a match. Is there an interface or baseclass that exposes the 'type' property that you could use?

Comment: There are too many uncertainties to be able to say anything useful about the problem.

Comment: @RobinBennett: "This looks through every type in every referenced assembly to find a match." I'm not sure what exactly you mean by that, but dynamic typing doesn't do that. While it may be the culprit here, I don't think it behaves how you're describing.

Comment: What is `objeto` anyway? It's not defined in the code.

Comment: "This code is running inside of a worker that reads the data from the server and send it to this function best regards" makes me wonder if `foreach` is a network call.

Comment: I'm not sure if the issue is with the printer or the code.  I would recommend as a test to create a string with the data instead of sending the data inside the for loop.  Then send the string at the end and see how long the printer takes to print.  I a little confused with the code having "PrintPageEventArgs e1" and then at the end of the for loop "p.Print()".  Is the last Print just to send just to have the printer feed out more paper?

Comment: tip: code needs refactoring so there is less `stuff` going on in the one method (has the bonus affect of being less headache inducing as well...)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks all for your answers. So, I've debug the code, and is taking around 500ms to do each loop. The foreach is only to print. When there's a request to print, it calls the function print sending the "objeto" that is the json object got from the http request. I will try "profile thing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to profile your code within Visual Studio, which is has  powerful profiling tools even in the free versions!
Then a good starting point will be 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2017
you may begin with the video linked in there.

Then you need to understand, if the slow performance is CPU Bound or if something (e.g. in that PrintC Object) is bound to external calls waiting or wait for a database or the actual printer.

Anything else is pure guessing as your code cannot be tested anywhere else without your external references.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks all for your answers.
So, I've debug the code, and is taking around 500ms to do each loop.
The foreach is only to print. When there's a request to print, it calls the function print sending the "objeto" that is the json object got from the http request.

I will try "profile thing"